# Limit, 0/0, square roots

Tags: limits

So i got this limits:
$$\lim_{x\to4}\frac{3-\sqrt{5+x}}{1-\sqrt{5-x}} $$

i multiplied by $$\frac{3+\sqrt{5+x}}{3+\sqrt{5+x}} $$and $$\frac{1+\sqrt{5-x}}{1+\sqrt{5-x}}$$ to try to remove the root, but went much further than that ,also trying to do without L'Hopital.

Comment: I would try  $$1-y^3=(1-y)(1+y+y^2)$$ to make the denominator rational. Take $y=\sqrt[3]{5-x}$

Comment: ill try with that, thanks btw :)

Comment: I believe you meant $\sqrt{5+x}$ instead of $\sqrt[3]{5+x}$.

Comment: god damn , yes its  $$\sqrt{5+x}$$ and $$\sqrt{5-x}$$

Comment: Do the multiplication  $(3-\sqrt{5+x})(3+\sqrt{5+x})$. We get $4-x$. Do the multiplication  $(1-\sqrt{5-x})(1+\sqrt{5-x})$. We get $x-4$. Cancel, we get $-1$. Now look how the other terms behave as $x\to 4$.

Comment: My advice did not work :-(

Comment: @miracle173: It is not easy to hit a moving target.

Comment: sry for that @miracle173 :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{3-\sqrt{5+x}}{1-\sqrt{5-x}}=\frac{4-x}{3+\sqrt{5+x}}\cdot\frac{1+\sqrt{5-x}}{-4+x}=-\frac{1+\sqrt{5-x}}{3+\sqrt{5+x}}\xrightarrow[x\to 4]{}-\frac26=-\frac13$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It's the root in the *denominator* you want to worry about. Think about using the fact that

$$a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

and how you might form this in the denominator. Your original approach has something of the right idea, but focus on the denominator and what factor is missing.

Comment: Why would the OP want to use that *cubic* identity?

Comment: It showed cubic before (typo)

Comment: @DonAntonio: The problem statement has changed. These were all cube roots originally, now they have been change to square roots, so the solution doesn't apply any more.

Comment: So I see, @MPW . Thanks.